# clickhouse JOIN tables with field in range

Tags: sql, database, join, left-join, clickhouse

I'm having trouble with the following problem
I have a table called ips(with column src_ext_ip in ipv4 format)
and a table with IP ranges and isp:

table ip_to_isp(ip_range_start,ip_range_end,isp) as ip_range_start and ip_range_end are in integer IP format.

I want to join both tables so that the first table ips will have its correct isp.

tried this:

```
"SELECT ips.src_ext_ip, ip_to_isp.isp FROM ips LEFT OUTER JOIN ip_to_isp ON IPv4StringToNum(ips.src_ext_ip) BETWEEN ip_to_isp.ip_range_start AND ip_to_isp.ip_range_end"
```

got this error:

```
DB::Exception: Unsupported JOIN ON conditions. Unexpected 'IPv4StringToNum(src_ext_ip) >= ip_range_start': While processing IPv4StringToNum(ip) >= ip_range_start. (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION)
```

also replaced the between with where and got:

```
 Code: 403. DB::Exception: Cannot get JOIN keys from JOIN ON section: src_ext_ip. (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION) (version 22.12.6.22 (official build))
```

how can I join these 2 tables without a common field?